# d3.js not working on local server

Tags: d3.js

d3.js is not appending the div as expected. Debuggin on FF 18+ and Firebug.

The d3 Object is returned (on alert message) but the chart object returns blank.

The d3.js lib is loading ok.

Here's the code

```
    <?php header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='js/d3.v3.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

            var chart = d3.select("#hurtme").append("div").attr("class", "chart");

            alert (d3);

            //chart.selectAll("div").data(data).enter().append("div").style("width", function(d) { return d * 10 + "px"; }).text(function(d) { return d; });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='hurtme'></div>
        hello
    </body>
</html>
```

What am I missing?

PS: I've discarted the browser imcompatibility since other examples from the web works fine.

PS2: Also tried using d3.v2.js and loading from source on `<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>`, no success so far.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your script is loaded and executed *before* the div comes into existence. Try moving the script tags after the div:

```
<div id='hurtme'></div>
<script> type='text/javascript'>
        var data = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
        var chart = d3.select("#hurtme").append("div").attr("class", "chart");
</script>
```

Or use an 'onload' function: [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload)

Comment: OMG... Anyway I didn't suspect that cause before I've tried using the 'body' tag instead of the 'div' object. Any way thx.

Comment: This is absolutely useful!